# Cyber Security - CentOS 8 Alternative

Tags: centos

I'm not sure if this is the correct community to ask this, if its not kindly point me to the correct one and I'll delete the question here and move.

I'm just diving into cyber security and I was tasked to start using CentOS 8 as the recommended operating system (to start with) but I just found out that CentOS 8 is dead.

Do you have any recommended alternatives to use that's just as good as CentOS 8?

Comment: Did you google for e.g. "CentOS 8 Alternative"?

Comment: lol i did, but im a bit overwhelmed with all the information, and stuck on what is the best option when its dealing with cyber security. i've read that centos 7 will continue its support until 2024 so im thinking should i use that, but then what happens after 2024 when it reaches its end of life, what would be my alternative then, im seeing a few negatives about using centos stream and thinking maybe should i just move away from centos and try ubuntu or oracle linux.

Comment: Well, "Cyber Security" is nothing but a "buzz-word". Better **[edit]** your question and [add more details](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) on what you want to achieve, what your real requirements are, etc. As it currently stands, we'd rather have to put your question on hold as it's much too broad. Are you asking as end-user concerned about your privacy? As a security researcher, pen tester, network admin… Too many facets, too many open questions – no way we could give good recommendations matching your needs without knowing them.